# Why cannot I import 'pd.read_html' in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run the following code in Jupyter notebook, but get "ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)", seems like dont recognize the HTML file that I need

```
DataUFC = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events')`
```

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 DataUFC = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_events')
```

I need to read HTML tables into a DataFrame objects.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you very much in advance

I tried to add another argument but i can't find what is the error, the kernel and pandas are running fine.

Comment: Have you done `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: yes, i did, i just forgot to put that line code in this post

Comment: can you add your full code ? I tried it and seems to work in terms of importing but not in terms of generating the data frame.